# When I import the mdxeditor component, the app goes blank

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm a newbie. I'm using electron to make an app and using the react framework, but when I want to use mdxeditor, the app displays blank.

this in src/renderer/src/components
/index.ts

```
export * from './ActionButtonsRow'
export * from './AppLayout'
export * from './Button'
export * from './DraggableTopBar'
// export * from './FloatingNoteTitle'
export * from './MarkdownEditor'
export * from './NotePreview'
export * from './NotePreviewList'
```

below is App.tsx

```
import { MDXEditor } from '@mdxeditor/editor'

export const MarkdownEditor = () => {
  return (
    <MDXEditor
      markdown={'#Hello from MDX Editor'}
      contentEditableClassName="outline-none min-h-screen max-w-none text-lg px-8 py-5 caret-yellow-500"
    />
  )
}
```

fix the problem, find the answer.

Comment: Are you giving us an order? What about you check your console and look for errors?